# Why only one image shows in viewflipper using Json data by ListArray?

Tags: android, json, list, android-volley, viewflipper

How to show the Json images in viewflipper in a listarray,logcat shows that it fetches all the images from the listarray but only one image shows on the emulator, why?

This is part of my code

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.ViewFlipper01);
        viewFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_in));
        viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_out));

 Log.d("VIEWFLIPPER size", String.valueOf(listSuperHeroes.size()));

                        for (int i = 0; i < listSuperHeroes.size(); i++) {
                            Log.d("VIEWFLIPPER PICS ", listSuperHeroes.get(i).getflag());
                            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                            Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                                    .load(listSuperHeroes.get(i).getflag())
                                    .centerCrop()
                                    .dontAnimate()
                                    .placeholder(R.drawable.logofresh)
                                    .into(imageView);
                            viewFlipper.addView(imageView);
                        }
                        viewFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
                        viewFlipper.setFlipInterval(3000);
```

LOGCAT

```
D/VIEWFLIPPER size: 10
D/VIEWFLIPPER PICS: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/china.png
D/VIEWFLIPPER PICS: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/india.png
D/VIEWFLIPPER PICS: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/unitedstates.png
D/VIEWFLIPPER PICS: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/indonesia.png
D/VIEWFLIPPER PICS: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/brazil.png
D/VIEWFLIPPER PICS: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/pakistan.png
D/VIEWFLIPPER PICS: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/nigeria.png
D/VIEWFLIPPER PICS: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/bangladesh.png
D/VIEWFLIPPER PICS: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/russia.png
D/VIEWFLIPPER PICS: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/japan.png
```

This is my whole code for the main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ViewFlipper viewFlipper;

    private ArrayList<SuperHeroes> listSuperHeroes = new ArrayList<>();

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
   RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    SuperHeroes setterGetterClass;
//    String tempoUrl[] = {"https://data.bigbenta.com/storeapp/images/2361/2016080912165157a95933e9591-lg.jpeg",
//            "http://marketplace.bigbenta.com/references/images/bigbenta_image_sm.png",
//            "http://staging.freshonline.ph/skin/frontend/rwd/default/images/slider/slider3.jpg",
//    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        adapter = new CardAdapter(listSuperHeroes, MainActivity.this);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
       layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
//layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,1);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        ///////ArrayList<SuperHeroes> listOfpics =  getData();
        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, Configg.DATA_URL,null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject req) {
                        //Dismissing progress dialog
                        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Loading Data", "Please wait...",false,false);
                        loading.dismiss();

                        //calling method to parse json array
                        parseData(req);

                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                        Log.d("VIEWFLIPPER size mo", String.valueOf(listSuperHeroes.size()));
                        //  listSuperHeroes.get(i).getflag()
//                        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                        for (int i = 0; i < listSuperHeroes.size(); i++) {
                            Log.d("VIEWFLIPPER PICS ", listSuperHeroes.get(i).getflag());
//                            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
//                                    .load(listSuperHeroes.get(i).getflag())
//                                    .placeholder(R.drawable.logofresh)
//                                    .resize(250, 200)
//                                    .into(imageView);
                        }

                        Log.d("VIEWFLIPPER size po", String.valueOf(listSuperHeroes.size()));
                        viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.ViewFlipper01);
                        viewFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,
                                android.R.anim.fade_in));
                        viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,
                                android.R.anim.fade_out));
                        for (int i = 0; i < listSuperHeroes.size(); i++) {
                            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                            Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                                    .load(listSuperHeroes.get(i).getflag().toString())
                                    .centerCrop()
                                    .dontAnimate()
                                    .placeholder(R.drawable.logofresh)
                                    .into(imageView);
                            viewFlipper.addView(imageView);
                        }
                        viewFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
                        viewFlipper.setFlipInterval(3000);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d("HELLO BIGBENTA", "Error: " + error.getMessage());

                    }
                });



        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);



        /////////////////////////////////////////////





    }





    private void parseData(JSONObject req) {

        try {

            JSONArray json = req
                    .getJSONArray("worldpopulation");


            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonOb = json
                        .getJSONObject(i);
                setterGetterClass = new SuperHeroes(jsonOb.getInt(Configg.TAG_rank),jsonOb.getString(Configg.TAG_country),jsonOb.getString(Configg.TAG_population),jsonOb.getString(Configg.TAG_flag));
                listSuperHeroes.add(setterGetterClass);
                Log.d("tag", setterGetterClass.getcountry().toString());
                Log.d("show: ", setterGetterClass.toString());



            }

            Log.d("parseData: ", setterGetterClass.toString());


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }










    }
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.edmeralarte.exambigbenta.MainActivity">


    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/ViewFlipper01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ff0"
        android:layout_height="220dp" >

    </ViewFlipper>





    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_main"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.7">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: i put it on bold letters so they could easily notice me, not shouting lolz, ok i'll edit the font :-)

Comment: I am working your code.... it's working fine What you take for listSuperHeroes.... Arraylist or other/

Comment: i passed a setter getter variable that contains JSON objects into listSuperHeroes

Comment: I edited my post for you to see the whole code on Main Activity